# Install Windows 8.1 Pro in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am thinking of installing Windows 8.1 using Virtual Box. I don't want to mess up anything so I have some questions.

1. My PC has 4 GB of RAM. If I use 2 GB for the virtual machine then will this memory be used solemnly for the VM and as a result only the remaining to be available for Ubuntu at all times, or is this the maximum memory that the VM can use when it is turned on?
2. If I want to delete the VM and everything installed in it (programs and files), is it enough to just press the delete or there are files that someone must delete/uninstall manually? I want the VM to provide a clean install and a clean uninstall respectfully so I don't want to leave data scattered around.
3. Is Virtual Box the best choice for Ubuntu or should I use something else?
4. Will Ubuntu have any issues after the creation of the virtual machine regarding its performance (when the VM is turned on and when it is turned off)?

I know that these may seem ridiculous questions but I have used virtual machines before without ever thinking about any of these. Also when I searched for these questions nobody seems to care about those and as a result I couldn't find any source to even mention them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All of the memory will be dedicated to the virtual machine when it is started. (I recommend that you buy more RAM if you want to use this VM regularly though.)
2. It is enough to just press Delete. That will delete the virtual machine entirely from your system.
3. Oracle VM VirtualBox is easily the best choice for running Windows 8.1 in a virtual machine. Just make sure you install the VirtualBox Guest Additions after you get Windows installed.
4. Ubuntu will (obviously) run slower when the VM is running. However, Ubuntu will not be slower when the VM is not running, as VirtualBox nor Windows will be running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only think that I didn't understand from your answer is about the memory. The memory will be dedicated only when the VM will be running or at all times? For example if I use 2GB for the VM them at all times I will have the remaining 2GB for the Ubuntu or only when I switch it on?

Comment: Only when the VM is on. If it's off, then VirtualBox obviously wouldn't be running so it can't use your memory.